# make a custom listView in android sorted by date with total

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to make a custom listView with some data and one section header for each day.
In this section header want to put date and total for each day.
I'm in trouble to calculate the total for each section header.
My data source is a database.
this look like this:
[image]

My Adapter:

```
public class CursorSectionAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public static final String TAG = "debug_adapter";

public static final String BABY_BOTTLE_TAG = "baby_bottle";
int i = 0;
private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;

private LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> mSections;
private LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> mSectionsDate;


private ArrayList mSectionIndex;

BaseAdapter baseAdapter;

private Cursor mCursor;
private static final int STATE_UNKNOWN = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 2;


public CursorSectionAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    this.mSections = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    this.mSectionsDate = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    this.mSectionIndex = new ArrayList();

    mCursor = c;
    findSection();
    cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    mCursor = cursor;
   // int i = cursor.getCount();
    findSection();
    super.changeCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.baby_bottle_item_layout, parent, false);
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    i++;


    TextView dateTimeTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BabyBottleItemDateTimeTextView);
    String dateTime[] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_DATETIME)).split(" ");
    dateTimeTv.setText(dateTime[1]);
    //Todo test dateTime not null
    TextView quantityTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BabyBottleItemQuantityTextView);
    String quantity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_QUANTITY));
    quantityTv.setText(quantity + "ml");

    TextView otherTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BabyBottleItemOtherTextView);
    TextView separator = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.separatorTextView);



    int cursorPos = mCursor.getPosition();
    switch (getItemViewType(cursorPos)) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:
            Log.d(TAG, "TYPE_ITEM");
            separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:

            String result = Utils.DateFromDataBaseToLocal(dateTime[0]); //Get date to european format
            //String result = String.format("%s-%s-%s",day,month,year);
            separator.setText(result + " Total : " ); // How get total....
            separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d(TAG, "TYPE_SEPARATOR");
            break;
    }

        int vitamine = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_VITAMIN));
        int iron = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_IRON));
        int saddle = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_SADDLE));
        int urin = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_URIN));
        boolean bVit = (vitamine != 0);
        boolean bIron = (iron != 0);
        boolean bSaddle = (saddle != 0);
        boolean bUrin = (urin != 0);


        String other = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(other);

        if (bVit) sb.append("Vitamine-");
        if (bIron) sb.append("Fer-");
        if (bUrin) sb.append("Urine-");
        if (bSaddle) sb.append("Selle-");
        int lio = sb.lastIndexOf("-");
        int l = (sb.length() - 1);
        if (lio == l && lio > 0) sb.deleteCharAt(lio);

        otherTv.setText(sb.toString());

}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mSectionsDate.containsValue(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
}

private void findSection() {
    if (mCursor != null) {
        int nSection = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int total = 0;
        mSections.clear();
        Log.d(BABY_BOTTLE_TAG, "find section : count : " + mCursor.getCount());

        int index = mCursor.getColumnIndex(BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_DATETIME);
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (mCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            String sectionName = mCursor.getString(index).split(" ")[0];
            String[] sectionName2 = mCursor.getString(index).split(" ");

            if (!mSections.containsKey(sectionName)) {
                mSections.put(sectionName, i + nSection);
                mSectionsDate.put(sectionName2[0], i);
                mSectionIndex.add(i);

                nSection++;
            }
            i++;


            //  mCursor.getString(2);
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Found " + mSections.toString() + " section");
        /// ;
    }
}
```

}

Here is my loader request in my activity:

```
 @Override
public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
            BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable._ID, // 0
            BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_QUANTITY, // 1
            BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_DATETIME, //2
            BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_URIN,//3
            BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_IRON,//4
            BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_SADDLE,//5
            BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_VITAMIN//6

    };

    // Filter results WHERE "_id" = 'babyId'
    String selection = BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.COLUMN_BABY_ID + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(babyId) };


    Uri testUri =BiberonDataBaseContract.BabyBottleTable.CONTENT_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(this.getBaseContext(),testUri,PROJECTION,selection,selectionArgs,null);
}
```

In my database COLUMN_DATETIME is stored in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format and quantity is an intger.
Have you got some idea please? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a dynamic arraylist which can contatin Integer, name it as date

```
List<Integer> date_20161216=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now add all values to it by converting it to intger, i.e.,

```
//suppose you want to add 225ml and 255ml,then
 String value=255ml;
date_20161216.add(Integer.parseInt(value.value.indexOf("m")));
```

Then when you want to add them

```
int total=0;
for(int i=0;i<date_20161216;i++){
   total=total+date_20161216.get(i));
}
```

use Total to paste value in header

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  this look like to be a good method. I try to implement it.